# Getting the average in a GROUP BY statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get the average of numbers in a query that uses both GROUP BY and ORDER BY but I don't know how to go about this.

This is my query:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) as tcount 
FROM issues 
GROUP BY location_id 
ORDER BY tcount DESC
```

How do I get the average here?

Comment: Does MySQL not have an avg() function?

Comment: The average of what? `id` does not make sense to me, as well as `location_id`. I wouldn't average that...

Answer (score 1):

Use `AVG()`

```
SELECT AVG(fieldtoaggregate) as average_value FROM table
```

If you want the average grouped by a field, you can use group by. Imagine you want the avegare age grouped by gender:

```
SELECT AVG(age) as average_age, gender FROM tb_user GROUP BY gender ORDER BY gender ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

You question is not clear  but seems you are looking for AVG()

```
SELECT COUNT(id) as tcount , avg(id) 
FROM issues 
GROUP BY location_id 
ORDER BY tcount DESC
```

or in general

```
SELECT COUNT(id) as tcount , avg(your_column) 
FROM issues 
GROUP BY location_id 
ORDER BY tcount DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
SELECT AVG(tcount)
FROM
(
SELECT COUNT(id) as tcount 
FROM issues 
GROUP BY location_id
) sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use AVG aggregate function :

```
SELECT location_id, AVG(id) as tavg 
  FROM issues 
 GROUP BY location_id 
 ORDER BY 1 DESC;
```

Shall be more meaningful to remove GROUP BY and ORDER BY:

```
SELECT AVG(id) as tavg 
  FROM issues;
```

[*SQL Fiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/849746/3)